# Testing for intra-subject agreement across categories

Tags: r, categorical-data, agreement-statistics

I am looking at whether there is agreement between a subject's standardized weight (light-for-age or heavy-for-age) in early life and adulthood. I have coded light-for-age as '1' and heavy-for-age as '2'. My data are as follows:

```
phase1=c(2,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2)
phase3=c(2,1,1,NA,2,1,2,1,NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, 2, NA, NA, 1, 2, NA, NA, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 2, 2, 1, 2, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, NA, NA, NA)
ydata=data.frame(phase1, phase3)
```

Phase 1 is early life and phase 3 is adulthood.

I am also interested in looking at whether those that are light-for-age ('1') in early life tend to remain light-for-age in adulthood. I tried calculating Fleiss' kappa using the irr package in R as follows:

```
library(irr)
phases=kappam.fleiss(ydata, exact=TRUE, detail=FALSE)
phases$value
```

and

```
phases2=kappam.fleiss(ydata[ydata$phase1==1, ], exact=TRUE, detail=FALSE)
    phases2$value
```

Based on the data in the second analysis, I'd have expected a very high agreement, but I get an extremely low kappa. Is there another coefficient that might work better for my dataset, which is relatively small and unbalanced? Or does anyone know of another test that might be appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

No chance-adjusted index of agreement is going to give you a high score:

Bennett et al.'s $S = 0.222$

Cohen's $\kappa = 0.267$

Gwet's $\gamma = 0.316$

Krippendorff's $\alpha = 0.211$

Scott's $\pi = 0.099$

However, I wonder if you need to perform a chance-adjustment at all. Are these categories of "light-for-age" and "heavy-for-age" based on subjective assessment or objective scales? If the latter case is true, then perhaps you can just use the percent observed agreement of $0.611$.